# Cache domain GET requests using Squid

Tags: iptables, reverse-proxy, cache, squid

I'm trying to cache requests to remote package repository, so I can access it without internet connection. All calls are via http GET to remote repo.

iptables entry to redirect requests to proxy

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d repo.domain --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3128 //redirect to squid
```

and `squid.conf`

```
acl cacheDomain dstdomain repo.domain
```

It doesn't seem to be working. Maybe it is only squid problem. Requests to remote repo are failing and no entries in `squid3/access.log` or `squid3/cache.log`.

What I'm doing wrong? 
Is this acl line enough to enable caching for this domain?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: It don't seem to be working. Maybe it is only squid problem. Requests to remote rep are failing and no entries in squid3/access.log / cache.log.

Comment: I'm new to squid and don't know how to configure this type of caching properly

Comment: @PsychoX, According to your iptables rule, you are forwarding request to port 8080 to port 3128. Are you accessing the repo domains on port 8080 or 80?. If it is on port 80, then change the iptables rule accordingly and see.

Comment: I'm accessing it on port 8080.

Comment: @PsychoX, may be you can post an example, how you are accessing it. Also make sure squid is listening on port 3128: `netstat -tlp | grep :3128`. You should also check your firewall rules: `iptables -S`.